# How to read a blob data URL in WKWebView?

Tags: xcode, macos, blob, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView, but when I click on a link that has the following URL:

```
blob:https://www.mycase.com/2963c6c0-24c1-418f-a314-88f7a2dbc713
```

Nothing happens. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) it describes:

> The only way to read content from a Blob is to use a FileReader.

So I presume there is no way `WKWebView` is able to read the Blob itself by some method. As `URLSession` fails to download the content when you feed it the blob URL.

A solution I came up with myself is to read the blob in JavaScript itself.

```
var script = ""

script = script + "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();"
script = script + "xhr.open('GET', '\(navigationURL)', true);"
script = script + "xhr.responseType = 'blob';"
script = script + "xhr.onload = function(e) { if (this.status == 200) { var blob = this.response; var reader = new window.FileReader(); reader.readAsBinaryString(blob); reader.onloadend = function() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.readBlob.postMessage(reader.result); }}};"
script = script + "xhr.send();"

self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil);
```

Then add a script message handler to fetch the content.

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "readBlob")

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.body)
}
```

It feels a bit cumbersome to do it like this, is there any other way?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: @DarshanMothreja see if this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702414/wkwebview-how-to-handle-blob-url/61703086#

Comment: For some reason the `didReceive message` callback does never get called. My blob looks very similar to your example. But your `script` does not seem to do the job.  Can you please show  more of your original workaround  example ? Thank you

Comment: In fact, I can change the script to an example-script such as `window.webkit.messageHandlers.readBlob.postMessage('test');` and everything works. But your complicated Request-script still does not seem to work. Do you know if it will work for images or videos being downloaded ?? What was your original download type for your code script-example ?

Comment: Hello. Your example with script does not work. xhr.onload never called. Maybe you have another way?

Comment: This has worked in the past (four years ago) if it doesn't know I am curious for a solution too. Sorry I can't help you any further.

Comment: Where is this blob: URL coming from? There's a lot of potential problems with URLs that have "blob:" as a scheme.