# WKWebView: How to handle BLOB URL

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I have my `WKWebView` when I click on a file to download it. I have a popup writing:

> No application configured to open the URL `blob:https// ...`

I tried to register a custom URL scheme `blob` to `WKWebView`, the application crash saying that this scheme is already supported by default.

However, when I click on the file, the delegate is not called:

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)`
```

So I can't even know when a blob url is clicked to try to download the file by injecting JavaScript.

My application is for macOS.

[image]

Comment: Yes I’m trying to open a url blob. Look at the post I added a picture

Comment: if there is a solution in JavaScript I will accept a solution with.  how can i listen for blob url to javascript and change the scheme?  Do you have a code idea?  I have already done research but without success

Comment: if nothing else works, you can try using a dataurl.  but see if setting CSP works: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' gap://ready file: ws://<path-to-ws-endpoint>; child-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: cdvfile:; img-src * 'self' data: blob:;" />`

Comment: This guy found a workaround that I guess is slightly better than having to convert to a dataurl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45065085/how-to-read-a-blob-data-url-in-wkwebview

Comment: I do not have access to the site code.  So I have to inject 'can you explain to me the code you advise me

Comment: I already saw what you tell me, put the listener does not work.  that does not send any message to my webview

Comment: Just in case it might help you. 
 Someone who has a full working program. 
 Also used data uri, but I don't see why you the binary string method wouldn't work either: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/108394#333195

Comment: that's my real problem I can't intercept it in the delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this is a really roundabout hack.  Scan all href and replace any blob urls detected with datauri.
EDIT: updated to show it running

```
function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
    a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
// not sure what elements you are going to intercept:
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(async (el)=>{
   const url = el.getAttribute('href');
   if( url.indexOf('blob:')===0 ) {
       let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
       blobToDataURL(blob, datauri => el.setAttribute('href',datauri));
   }
});
```

```js
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).buffer]);
test.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([31,32,33,34,35]).buffer]);
test1.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([51,52,53,54]).buffer]);
test2.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);



function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
    a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( event.target.matches('a[href^="blob:"]') )
     (async el=>{
       const url = el.href;
       const blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
       blobToDataURL(blob, datauri => el.href=datauri);
     })(event.target);
});

// not sure what elements you are going to intercept:
/*document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(async (el)=>{
   const url = el.href;
   if( url.indexOf('blob:')===0 ) {
       let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
       blobToDataURL(blob, datauri => el.href=datauri);
   }
});*/
```

```html
<a id="test">test</a>
<a id="test1">test</a>
<a id="test2">test</a>
```

Example of data uri conversion on click:

```js
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).buffer]);
test.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([31,32,33,34,35]).buffer]);
test1.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);
b=new Blob([new Int8Array([51,52,53,54]).buffer]);
test2.href=URL.createObjectURL(b);



function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
    a.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if ( event.target.matches('a[href^="blob:"]') ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     (async el=>{
       const url = el.href;
       const blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
       blobToDataURL(blob, datauri => window.open(el.href=datauri,el.target||'_self'));
     })(event.target);
   }
});

// not sure what elements you are going to intercept:
/*document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(async (el)=>{
   const url = el.href;
   if( url.indexOf('blob:')===0 ) {
       let blob = await fetch(url).then(r => r.blob());
       blobToDataURL(blob, datauri => el.href=datauri);
   }
});*/
```

```html
<a id="test">test</a>
<a id="test1">test</a>
<a id="test2">test</a>
```

Comment: what if i don't want to scan for blob links, but listen as soon as a blob link is clicked?  Because in a webapp the link is not always on the main page but after clicking on a button

Comment: use addEventListener instead.  The async callback might make it awkward.  Just make sure you preventDefault

Comment: to make an addEventListener, the element must exist when the page loads?  Or add a listener to the window?  Can you show me an example

Comment: right, you'd have to have it execute after the DOM is ready.   I'm not sure if injecting it into the WebView will cause any differences.  It most likely shouldn't.  Just remember that this is basically doing a base64 conversion after each click.  Probably not a good idea with big files.   If that SO link can work, it will probably be better than this.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help

Comment: np.  Let me (us) know if you find a better solution in the future.